# Autoit script to extract all ip address from string

Tags: autoit

I am new in autoit, I want to extract all ip address from this string in array format

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <array.au3>

$str = "ghg shjsja 192.168.1.2 hbkjNKKSJKKN HKJCBKJLKKL 12.15.14.45 
        KJBKJABCKBNDKQ djfsjdkfhnwk kjwenfkjdsnf knfflksnf KHBKJABCKJQDH 
        1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2"

$copy = StringRegExp($str,"((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})",3)
MsgBox(0,"",$copy[0])`
```

i am getting all ip when i skip one step, means i will get second ip when i use $copy[2]. i want to extract all ip without skipping the step.

Comment: you must use from regular expressions for find them. https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "ghg shjsja 192.168.1.2 hbkjNKKSJKKN HKJCBKJLKKL 12.15.14.45 " & _
       "KJBKJABCKBNDKQ djfsjdkfhnwk kjwenfkjdsnf knfflksnf KHBKJABCKJQDH " & _
       "1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2"

$copy = StringRegExp($str, "((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})", 3)

For $i = 0 To UBound($copy) -1
    ConsoleWrite($copy[$i] & @CRLF)
    MsgBox(0, "", $copy[$i])
Next
```

Will output

```
192.168.1.2
12.15.14.45
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

instead of

```
192.168.1.2
1.
12.15.14.45
14.
1.1.1.1
1.
2.2.2.2
2.
```

The `?:` at the start of the inner capture group makes
it not capture and be just a group. The outer group
captures the inner group along with other characters
within the outer capture group as a single [step|capture].